# PyQGIS (QgsProject.instance().homePath())

Tags: pyqgis

I used this line of code in PyQGIS to get to project's home path.

```
path=os.path.join(QgsProject.instance().homePath(), "tt.gpkg").replace("\\","/")
```

Now I thought this is the path to where the project lies. But it comes that this is the path to where first/original project was saved.

Is that so or I might be wrong here?

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Comment: is it giving a  path to original Qgis project, from which was conecutively been saved some number of Qgis projects / Save-as   ? I have tested and it seems so.

Answer (score 5):

When you save the project with a different name, the project that is open now is the one in the path you just saved. QGIS closes the original project.

Let's say the project's path is `C:\test1\project1.qgz`. If you save as `project2.qgs` to `C:\test2`, QGIS closes `C:\test1\project1.qgz` and loads `C:\test2\project2.qgz`.

Therefore, `homePath` returns `C:\test2` after saving as `project2.qgz`.